# Meteor Iron Router resubscribe on Rights change with meteor-roles

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am writing a meteor application with a user-role-system (`alanning:roles`) My Roles are group based. When a user knows my group url, it is allowed to access the group an get the role "defaultUser" in this group.

localUser is allowed to subscribe to all the local stuff of a group.

based on the group's ID, I also publish some contents.

The Problem is: the Subscription does not resubscribe.

Workflow:

1. user accesses app,
2. calls meteor-method to get the default role
3. gets the default role
4. subscribes to a publication
5. the publication (complete-group) publishes the contents if the user has the right role

My Publication looks like:

```
Meteor.publish "thisGroupPublic", (id) ->
    return db.groups.find({_id: id}, {fields: {onlypublicones...}}

Meteor.publishComposite "thisGroupReactive", (id) ->
    return {
        find: () ->
            if !Roles.userIsInRole(@userId, "defaultUser", id)
                @ready()
                console.log("[thisGroupReactive] => No Rights")
                return;

            return db.groups.find({_id: id});

        children: [
            {
                find: (group) ->
                    return db.contents.find({groups: {$in: [group._id]}}, {fields: {apikey: 0}})
            }
        ]
    }
```

The user subscribes the subscription "thisGroupPublic" when the user is on the login page and gets the role "defaultUser" on its first visit to the group as a logged in user. But how do I need to configure `iron:router` to 
resubscribe this subscription that the contents are shown and not only the public stuff?

Comment: Just to be clear: the user is on one route which doesn't change. Some piece of data changes while the user is on this route and you want to send something to the route to re-subscribe to something based on this data change, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say that the user is on a route `/something`

You have some data that changes and you create a session variable:

`Session.set("someDataThatChanges", myChangedData)`

Your publish function takes some sort of input, which it uses to return different data from the collection:

```
Meteor.publish("myCollection", function(input){

  return myCollection.find( 
    // do something here based on 'input' 
  );

});
```

Iron Router has a `.subscribe` method that is the same as `Meteor.subscribe` and also a `subscriptions` key that takes a function. You can wrap a `Tracker.autorun` around your `.subscribe` and put in your session variable to automatically re-subscribe to something based on the changing value of that session variable.

```
Router.route("/something", {

  name: "templateName",

  // a place to put your subscriptions
  subscriptions: function() {

    console.log("this in router ", this);

    Tracker.autorun(function(){
      this.subscribe('myCollection', Session.get("someDataThatChanges");
    });

  },

});
```